# Manage Timeout with actionon Google and DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm tryng to create a Chat Bot using DialogFlow with webHooks and Actions on Google.

I need to manage a timeout i.e when the end user did not use the Chat Bot for a configured amount of time, i need to exit from conversation without user interaction, same result as described here but without any input.

[conversation-exits](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits)

I cannot find info about this automatic triggered action any hint?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversation-exits you are referring is for exiting the Conversation when the user says Cancel, Exit, Stop etc. 
To handle No User Interaction, you could do the following:

- Create a new Intent and set event = "`actions_intent_NO_INPUT`"
- In the webhook, if this intent is triggered, set the rePrompt count flag and ask for user input.
- If the count reaches 2-3 (as desired), end the conversation by using `conv.close()`

Check out the following page on [RePrompts and No Inputs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts) and [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices).

Comment: Thank you a lot, googling for 1 hours with wrong search term....I just created an Intent with this event but testing on https://console.actions.google.com this intent  is never called, may be it works only on device?

Comment: yes, on the device it works. On the simulator, you may try to enter a blank (click space bar 1-2 times). Sometimes that works.

Comment: i just tried the no user interaction from emulator inserting  some space and even using Surface Speaker configuration clicking on the ad hoc icon (simulating no input)  and simulating the NO Input Event, and it seems to work fine, intent with associated event "actions_intent_NO_INPUT" is called. But from a device (mobile phone Android) , without entering any input  the intent is not called, it seems that the Bot wait forever for the input, so basically it seems that there is no "timeout" or similar concept associated to user input, or may be i miss some configuration?

Comment: yes, there are issues. you may contact the support team at Google for raising a bug.